# Is "needless to say" an absolute phrase?

Tags: absolute-constructions

Would the phrase "*needless to say*" be an absolute phrase (adverbial phrase that modifies the entire clause after it)?

> "*Needless to say, I was super happy.*"

Comment: Needless to say, I'd like to know what the definition of "absolute phrase" is with reference or possible link.

Comment: http://www.testmagic.com/grammar/explanations/phrases/absolute-phrases-introduction.asp

Comment: I'd call it a pragmatic marker ... of the modal, veridical (commenting on the [near-] impossibility that the statement in the matrix sentence be wrong]; it's certainly parenthetical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[One definition](http://www.testmagic.com/grammar/explanations/phrases/absolute-phrases-introduction.asp) of "absolute phrase" that is somewhat more extended than the one in the original question is as follows:

> An ABSOLUTE PHRASE is a MODIFIER (quite often a PARTICIPLE), or a
>   modifier and a few other words, that attaches to a SENTENCE or a NOUN,
>   with no CONJUNCTION. An absolute phrase cannot contain a FINITE VERB.
>
> Absolute phrases usually consist of a noun and a modifier that
>   modifies this noun, NOT another noun in the sentence.
>
> Absolute phrases are optional in sentences, i.e., they can be removed
>   without damaging the grammatical integrity of the sentence. Since
>   absolute phrases are optional in the sentence, they are often set off
>   from the sentence with commas or, less often, with dashes. We normally
>   explain absolute phrases by saying that they modify entire sentences,
>   rather than one word. This is an important concept, since many similar
>   phrases that we work with modify other words. For example, adjectives
>   modify nouns, and adverbs can modify verbs, adjectives, and other
>   adverbs. That said, however, in some cases, it seems to make more
>   sense to say that absolute phrases modify nouns.

The phrase "needless to say" has been used in the same fashion [since the 15th century](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/needless+to+say) in English (originally "needless to speak") and is an excellent example of an absolute phrase similar to [other examples](http://www.testmagic.com/grammar/explanations/phrases/absolute-phrases-introduction.asp) of absolute phrases such as:

> - **Her determination stronger than ever**, Nexisa resolved not to give up until she had achieved her dreams.
> - **The sun shining bright and the pale blue sky forming a backdrop of the Sacre Coeur**, Carl stepped into his future as a traveler and
>     observer.
> - Still young boys, Matt and Erin Billy awoke early one Christmas morning with sleepy eyes, **completely unaware that they were sleeping
>     not in the beds they had gone to sleep in, but in one of their
>     presents that year -- a new set of bunk beds.**
> - We finished the hearty meal quickly, **our appetites satisfied, our minds at peace.**
> - **All things being equal**, the active voice tends to be correct more often than the passive on standardized tests.

Comment: Could you please update the link, and attribute?